# Escaping keywords with a slash in my grammar

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a small subset of Doxygen.

In doxygen you can escape commands by prepending `\` to commands. So `@brief` is a command and `\@brief` shows up in the text.

But I'm having trouble recognizing the escape sequence.

I have defined my rules as:

```
beginSlash = Combine((~Literal('\\').suppress() | WordStart()) + Literal('\\') + ~FollowedBy(oneOf(r'\ @')))
beginAt = Combine(~Literal('\\').suppress() + '@')
beginMarker = (beginAt | beginSlash).setName('BeginMarker')

body = SkipTo(beginMarker | StringEnd()).setResultsName('body')
```

Now when trying to match it does not work

```
assert body.parseString('this is \@brief').body == 'this is @brief'
```

It returns

```
>       assert body.parseString('this is a \\@brief').body == 'this is @brief'
E       assert 'this is a \\' == 'this is @brief'
E         - this is a \\
E         + this is @brief
```

Can anyone provide me on some insight on where my thought process is at fault here?

I chose to separate the beginmarkers from the command names so i can easily expand the commands without having to worry about escaping the `@` or `\` for every command.

Comment: It looks like this is working perfectly. body is defined as `SkipTo(beginMarker)` and beginMarker specifies the leading '@', which matches the @ in @brief. I think your use of SkipTo is making this more confusing, try using searchString instead of parseString, and just search for the interesting bits.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I don't understand why it's matching the `@` because it is preceded by the ` \\` which, i thought would not match `~Literal('\\')` , thus preventing `\@` from matching.

Comment: Ah, SkipTo, scanString, and searchString all have the same problem here. They all go character by character looking for a match - if no match is found, the test location is advanced by 1 and tried again. So when positioned at the '\' before '@', there is indeed no match. But then when the test location advances by 1, at the '@' character, there *is* a match. It looks like you will have to expand your search string to include the possibility of a '\@' substring so that it will get matched instead of getting skipped.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire i almost thought that. How do i expand the search string to include that possibility?

Comment: Why does `beginSlash` end with `~FollowedBy(oneOf(r'\ @'))`? You will need to define an expression that does match a word starting with '\@', something like `Combine(WordStart() + '\@' + Word(alphas))`, which should match '\@brief', and add that to your SkipTo target.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire The use case case was `\\@brief` for that `~FollowedBy` construct.